# Is it possible to use condition in array or object in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a condition like this:

```
if($_POST['title'])
{
     $query
        ->orWhere('title' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['title'] . '%');
}
elseif($_POST['description'])
{
     $query
        ->orWhere('description' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['description'] . '%');
}
elseif($_POST['tag'])
{
     $query
        ->orWhere('tag' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['tag'] . '%');
}
elseif($_POST['title'] && $_POST['tag'] )
{
     $query
        ->orWhere('title' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['title'] . '%')
        ->orWhere('tag' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['tag'] . '%');
}
.
.
.
```

I want to now Is it possible to write this code in shorter way in php?

THIS IS WRONG but for example like this:

```
$query
 if($_POST['title'])  ->orWhere('title' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['title'] . '%');
 if($_POST['tag'])  ->orWhere('tag' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['tag'] . '%');
 if($_POST['description'])  ->orWhere('description' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $_POST['description'] . '%');
```

Comment: No, thats not possible

Comment: Create the statement first and then append it to a query variable

Comment: It's not possible if you want to keep elseif functionality.

Comment: To make shorter you can use function for this,Also both logic is not matched, Above one is `if...else...` and below one is only `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not exact** but, you can get the idea that how you can make a common function to check

```
$params = ["title","description","tag"];
$query = orIfMatchAll($query,$params);

function orIfMatchAll($query,$params){
    foreach($params as $param){
        if(isset($_POST[$param]){
            $query->orWhere($param,'LIKE',"%".$_POST[$param]."%");
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```